# Door hitting jamb on hinge side

Tags: doors, replacement

I replaced an old solid core door without replacing the frame.  I cut out the area on the door so the hinges would be flush.  Now the door hits the jamb on the lower hinge side.  What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: picture please ......

Comment: Pictures are needed so we can see.  Imagine the cut outs are not quite right, but pictures will help to fix.

Comment: your floor is not level or the jamb is not plumb. no worries. starting at the good side, set a scribe (aka 8th grade protractor) to that gap, then leave a trace on the door by sliding along the floor to the hinge side and cut along the line; it should now fit the floor like a glove, maybe needing some weather striping if there's too big a gap.

Comment: You mean it doesn't close properly because it's squeezing the jamb on the hinge side when it closes, in effect making it feel a bit 'springy' as it shuts?